Self-Energy of a Conducting Shell based on Surface Charge Distribution
If a charge $q$ is given to a shell of radius $r$ (conducting or non-conducting) it's self-energy is $kq^2/2r$, $k$ being Coulomb's constant.
But if the shell is conducting and the charge on the inner surface is  $-q$ and on the outer surface is $2q$, then should the shell be considered a combination of two shells, one of charge $-q$ and the other of $2q$? In this case the self energy turns out to be $5kq^2/2r$.
But if we only consider the net charge on the shell, the energy is still $kq^2/2r$.
Which one is correct?

If the shell is conducting, it cannot have charge separation on inner and outer surfaces. This is possible, however, for a non-conducting shell. In this case, the total energy still remains $kq^2/2r$, since there is an additional (negative) contribution from the interaction between the negative and positive charges. For a thin spherical non-conducting shell with charge $-q$ on the inner surface and charge $+2q$ on the outer surface, the total energy is given by
\begin{align}
E_\text{total} &= E_\text{outer} + E_\text{inner} + E_\text{interaction} \\
&= \frac{k(2q)^2}{2r} + \frac{k(-q)^2}{2r} + \frac{k(-q)(2q)}{r} \\
&= \frac{kq^2}{2r}
\end{align}

Thank you, I thought of this after the asking the question too. Regarding the first line, if we were to place a charge +q at the centre of the shell, can there be charge separation in a conducting shell in this case?

You're correct, an internal charge would definitely create charge separation. The question asked for self-energy which seemed to imply the absence of other interacting charges. In that case, there will be contributions from the interactions with the central charge too, though.
